# Why do I get AWS Greengrass Core Fleet Provisioning failing with error authorization failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to setup fleet provisioning with AWS and I am following all the direction from the AWS Documentation. Everything seems to be fine and when I run the command for installation of Greengrass Core, I get an Authorization Failure error. I really can't seew why it fails. I hope you can help me out.

Here is my logs from AWS CloudWatch:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-13 00:01:09.102",
    "logLevel": "ERROR",
    "traceId": "4484c5c5-eb31-6a44-9a23-6cf3458aa4ff",
    "accountId": "790513853565",
    "status": "Failure",
    "eventType": "Connect",
    "protocol": "MQTT",
    "clientId": "Core_MyGreengrassCore",
    "principalId": "ba2984c5eca202812a3ed6d74855bf494d472328603a7b080bf82679375af819",
    "sourceIp": "80.57.107.22",
    "sourcePort": 55974,
    "reason": "AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE",
    "details": "Authorization Failure"
}
```

Here is the log from greengrass.log on the core device:

```
    2021-12-13T00:01:02.881Z [WARN] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Shutting down Nucleus due to external signal. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.883Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: system-shutdown. {main=services.main:FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.895Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: effective-config-dump-complete. {file=/greengrass/v2/config/effectiveConfig.yaml}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.897Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-16) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.896Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-15) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=main, currentState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.902Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-20) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.897Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-17) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.903Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-set-state. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=RUNNING, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.897Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-18) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.897Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-19) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-close. Service is now closing. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.897Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Waiting for services to shutdown. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.903Z [INFO] (FleetStatusService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-set-state. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=RUNNING, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.903Z [INFO] (TelemetryAgent-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-set-state. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=RUNNING, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.904Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-set-state. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=RUNNING, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.904Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: Stopping backingTask start. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.904Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-set-state. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.905Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: Stopping backingTask start. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.905Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-set-state. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.905Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-12) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-run-interrupted. Service interrupted while running startup. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.906Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-2) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: Cancelling all telemetry scheduled tasks.. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.906Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-run-interrupted. Service interrupted while running startup. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.906Z [INFO] (TelemetryAgent-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-set-state. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.907Z [INFO] (FleetStatusService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-set-state. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.908Z [INFO] (Serialized listener processor) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: executor-service-shutdown-initiated. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.908Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper: Interrupted while subscribing to Iot Jobs descriptions topic. {ThingName=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.908Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-6) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.ShadowDeploymentListener: Interrupted while subscribing to device shadow topics. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.910Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Waiting for executors to shutdown. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.910Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: executor-service-shutdown-complete. {executor-terminated=false, scheduled-executor-terminated=true}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.911Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: context-shutdown-initiated. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.914Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-6) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Failed to run MQTT spooler. {}
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@65576070 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d19248b[Shutting down, pool size = 4, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.triggerSpooler(MqttClient.java:424)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.publish(MqttClient.java:521)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.WrapperMqttClientConnection.publish(WrapperMqttClientConnection.java:96)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.iot.iotshadow.IotShadowClient.PublishGetNamedShadow(IotShadowClient.java:251)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.ShadowDeploymentListener.publishToGetDeviceShadowTopic(ShadowDeploymentListener.java:326)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.ShadowDeploymentListener.lambda$setupShadowCommunications$2(ShadowDeploymentListener.java:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-12-13T00:01:02.915Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Connecting to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.915Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper: Interrupted while subscribing to Iot jobs event notifications topic. {ThingName=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.916Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Connection interrupted. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:02.918Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Failed to run MQTT spooler. {}
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@7062564d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d19248b[Shutting down, pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.triggerSpooler(MqttClient.java:424)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.publish(MqttClient.java:521)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.WrapperMqttClientConnection.publish(WrapperMqttClientConnection.java:96)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsClientWrapper.PublishDescribeJobExecution(IotJobsClientWrapper.java:170)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper.requestNextPendingJobDocument(IotJobsHelper.java:469)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper.subscribeToJobsTopics(IotJobsHelper.java:487)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper.lambda$setupCommWithIotJobs$5(IotJobsHelper.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-12-13T00:01:02.940Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Failed to run MQTT spooler. {}
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@c1770ff rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6d19248b[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.triggerSpooler(MqttClient.java:424)
    at com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient.publish(MqttClient.java:521)
    at com.aws.greengrass.util.MqttChunkedPayloadPublisher.publish(MqttChunkedPayloadPublisher.java:54)
    at com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService.uploadFleetStatusServiceData(FleetStatusService.java:457)
    at com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService.updateFleetStatusUpdateForAllComponents(FleetStatusService.java:293)
    at com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper.lambda$setupCommWithIotJobs$5(IotJobsHelper.java:364)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-12-13T00:01:02.941Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: fss-status-update-published. Status update published to FSS. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:03.182Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Unable to connect to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)

2021-12-13T00:01:03.182Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Error subscribing. {topic=$aws/things/Core_MyGreengrassCore/jobs/notify-namespace-aws-gg-deployment}
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.AsyncCallback$1.onFailure(AsyncCallback.java:27)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    ... 1 more

2021-12-13T00:01:03.184Z [INFO] (Thread-1) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: context-shutdown-complete. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:05.394Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.Platform: Getting platform instance com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.unix.linux.LinuxPlatform.. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.425Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.Platform: Getting platform instance com.aws.greengrass.util.platforms.unix.linux.LinuxPlatform.. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.445Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: No ongoing deployment detected. Proceed as default. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.519Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.config.Configuration: config-loading. Read configuration from a file path. {path=/greengrass/v2/config/config.tlog}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.598Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: effective-config-dump-complete. {file=/greengrass/v2/config/effectiveConfig.yaml}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.766Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: system-start. Launch Nucleus. {configPath=/greengrass/v2/config, rootPath=/greengrass/v2, version=2.5.2}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.879Z [INFO] (main) software.amazon.awssdk.eventstreamrpc.RpcServer: IpcServer started.... {}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.926Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.security.SecurityService: Register crypto key service provider. {keyType=file}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.927Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.security.SecurityService: Register crypto key service provider. {keyType=file}
2021-12-13T00:01:07.930Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.spool.Spool: Spooler has been configured. {maxSizeInBytes=2621440, storageType=Memory, keepQos0WhenOffline=false}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.049Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: DockerApplicationManagerService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.050Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: DeploymentService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.050Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: UpdateSystemPolicyService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.051Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: FleetStatusService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.051Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: TelemetryAgent. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.052Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: TokenExchangeService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: DockerApplicationManagerService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: DeploymentService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: UpdateSystemPolicyService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: FleetStatusService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: TelemetryAgent. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.088Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: Found Plugin: TokenExchangeService. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.089Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: serviceImplementors: {UpdateSystemPolicyService:class com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService...}. {}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.091Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Attempt to load service from plugins. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.103Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Attempt to load service from plugins. {serviceName=main}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.109Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Attempt to load service from plugins. {serviceName=DeploymentService}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.786Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Attempt to load service from plugins. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.794Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: Attempt to load service from plugins. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.815Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Connecting to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.848Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.Kernel: effective-config-dump-complete. {file=/greengrass/v2/config/effectiveConfig.yaml}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.848Z [INFO] (main) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.KernelLifecycle: system-start. {main=services.main:NEW}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.851Z [INFO] (FleetStatusService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-set-state. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.851Z [INFO] (FleetStatusService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-set-state. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.855Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-set-state. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.857Z [INFO] (FleetStatusService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.status.FleetStatusService: service-set-state. {serviceName=FleetStatusService, currentState=STARTING, newState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.858Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-set-state. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.858Z [INFO] (DeploymentService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.DeploymentService: service-set-state. {serviceName=DeploymentService, currentState=STARTING, newState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.860Z [INFO] (TelemetryAgent-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-set-state. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.860Z [INFO] (TelemetryAgent-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-set-state. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.861Z [INFO] (TelemetryAgent-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.telemetry.TelemetryAgent: service-set-state. {serviceName=TelemetryAgent, currentState=STARTING, newState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.861Z [INFO] (aws.greengrass.Nucleus-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.861Z [INFO] (aws.greengrass.Nucleus-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.862Z [INFO] (main-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=main, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.862Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: generic-service-finished. Nothing done. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.862Z [INFO] (aws.greengrass.Nucleus-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=STARTING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.862Z [INFO] (aws.greengrass.Nucleus-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=FINISHED, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.864Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: Shutdown initiated. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.864Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-8) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: generic-service-shutdown. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.864Z [INFO] (aws.greengrass.Nucleus-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=aws.greengrass.Nucleus, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.867Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-set-state. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=NEW, newState=INSTALLED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.870Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-set-state. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.871Z [INFO] (UpdateSystemPolicyService-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.UpdateSystemPolicyService: service-set-state. {serviceName=UpdateSystemPolicyService, currentState=STARTING, newState=RUNNING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.871Z [INFO] (main-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=main, currentState=INSTALLED, newState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.871Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-13) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: generic-service-finished. Nothing done. {serviceName=main, currentState=STARTING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.871Z [INFO] (main-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=main, currentState=STARTING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.871Z [INFO] (main-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=main, currentState=FINISHED, newState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.872Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-13) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: Shutdown initiated. {serviceName=main, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.872Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-13) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: generic-service-shutdown. {serviceName=main, currentState=STOPPING}
2021-12-13T00:01:08.872Z [INFO] (main-lifecycle) com.aws.greengrass.lifecyclemanager.GenericExternalService: service-set-state. {serviceName=main, currentState=STOPPING, newState=FINISHED}
2021-12-13T00:01:09.122Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Unable to connect to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)

2021-12-13T00:01:09.123Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Error subscribing. {topic=$aws/things/Core_MyGreengrassCore/jobs/$next/namespace-aws-gg-deployment/get/accepted}
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.AsyncCallback$1.onFailure(AsyncCallback.java:27)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    ... 1 more

2021-12-13T00:01:09.123Z [WARN] (pool-2-thread-5) com.aws.greengrass.deployment.IotJobsHelper: No connection available during subscribing to Iot Jobs descriptions topic. Will retry in sometime. {ThingName=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)

2021-12-13T00:01:19.920Z [INFO] (pool-2-thread-6) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Connecting to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
2021-12-13T00:01:20.146Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Unable to connect to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}
software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttClientConnection.onConnectionComplete(MqttClientConnection.java:139)

2021-12-13T00:01:20.146Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.MqttClient: Error subscribing. {topic=$aws/things/Core_MyGreengrassCore/shadow/name/AWSManagedGreengrassV2Deployment/update/accepted}
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.mqtt.MqttException: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
```

Here is the command I use to install Greengrass Core:

```
sudo -E java -Droot="/greengrass/v2" -Dlog.store=FILE -jar ./GreengrassInstaller/lib/Greengrass.jar --aws-region eu-west-2 --trusted-plugin ./GreengrassInstaller/aws.greengrass.FleetProvisioningByClaim.jar --init-config ./GreengrassInstaller/config.yaml --component-default-user ggc_user:ggc_group --setup-system-service true --deploy-dev-tools true
```

Here is the config.yaml file where it is supposed to get the data it needs:

```
 ---
services:
  aws.greengrass.Nucleus:
    version: "2.5.2"
  aws.greengrass.FleetProvisioningByClaim:
    configuration:
      rootPath: /greengrass/v2
      awsRegion: "REGION"
      iotDataEndpoint: "ENDPOINT"
      iotCredentialEndpoint: "CREDENTIALENDPOINT"
      iotRoleAlias: "ROLEALIAS"
      provisioningTemplate: "PROVISIONINGTEMPLATE"
      claimCertificatePath: "/greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.pem.crt"
      claimCertificatePrivateKeyPath: "/greengrass/v2/claim-certs/claim.private.pem.key"
      rootCaPath: "/greengrass/v2/AmazonRootCA1.pem"
      templateParameters:
        ThingName: "MyGreengrassCore"
        ThingGroupName: "MyGreengrassCoreGroup"
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in your logs you have a line regarding the MQTT connection your IoT device is attempting to establish with AWS IoT Core. Based on the following error appearing in your logs it seems Greengrass was not able to connect with AWS IoT core:

*2021-12-13T00:01:09.122Z [ERROR] (Thread-4) com.aws.greengrass.mqttclient.AwsIotMqttClient: Unable to connect to AWS IoT Core. {clientId=Core_MyGreengrassCore}*

This is most likely because you have not provided the right certificates & settings requried for Greengrass to connect to AWS IoT core.

As specified in AWS guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/fleet-provisioning.html#run-greengrass-core-v2-installer-fleet): you need to specify the right settings in your config files, namely

- awsRegion: The AWS Region where you created the provisioning template and other resources.
- iotDataEndpoint: The iotDataEndpoint with your AWS IoT data endpoint.
- iotCredentialEndpoint: The iotCredentialEndpoint with your AWS IoT credentials endpoint.
- iotRoleAlias:  The name of the token exchange role alias.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/fleet-provisioning.html#retrieve-iot-endpoints) should specify how to obtain these IoT endpoints above, using AWS CLI

Once you set those parameters in the config file correctly, Greengrass should install the device properly.

*Note: This is for Greengrass version 2.0*